# How do you pass rails 3 forms params into an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have a nested form (using accepts_nested_attributes_for in respective models):

```
<%= form_for(:technician, :url => {:controller => 'pos', :action => 'create_ticket'}) do |f| %>  
   <%= f.fields_for :service do |s| %>  
       <%= s.text_field :name %>  
       <%= s.text_field :name %> 
       <%= s.text_field :name %>  
       <%= s.text_field :name %>  
   <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

This works fine if I only have one s.text_field.  But once I add additional text_fields, it doesn't run properly.  If you look at the source code, the  id and name are the same for all six?

How do I put these params into an array?  [so that I can isolate them like this:]

```
service1 = Service.named(params[:technician][:service][1][:name])
```

(I've tried the method described on railscasts episode 192, but it didn't work either).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error, I've hacked something that works (but please let me know if you know a better, more eloquent way):

in view:

```
<%= form_for(:technician, :url => {:controller => 'pos', :action => 'create_ticket'}) do |f| %>  
  <% for @i in 1..6 do %>  
    <%= f.fields_for "services[#{@i}]" do |s| %>  
    <% end %>  
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

in controller:

```
 for i in 1..6 do  
        @service = Service.named(params[:technician][:services][i.to_s][:name]).first  
 end
```

make sure you turn i into string